# I want to write a local json file by using function that collect value from html, I struggle at make a function write data to json

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I can figure out how to write the data into local jsonfile, i create this function to use in html

```
 addem(first:string, last:string, email:string, tel:string, gender:string, birthdate:string){
   var dd ={ 
    "id": 1,
    "first": first,
    "last": last,
    "tel": tel,
    "email": email,
    "gender": gender,
    "birthdate": birthdate
    };
    var theJSON = JSON.stringify(dd);
    var uri = "data:application/json;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(theJSON);
    

}
```

I want json file to store like this
`[{ "id": 1, "first": "Sebastian", "last": "the great", "tel": "xxxxxxxx", "email":"hehe", "gender":"ชาย", "birthdate":"1/01/2007" }, { "id": 2, "first": "Sebastian", "last": "the good", "tel": "xxxxxxxx", "email":"hehe", "gender":"ชาย", "birthdate":"1/01/2007" }, { "id": 3, "first": "Sebastian", "last": "the best", "tel": "xxxxxxxx", "email":"hehe", "gender":"ชาย", "birthdate":"1/01/2007" }, { "id": 4, "first": "Sebastian", "last": "the better", "tel": "xxxxxxxx", "email":"hehe", "gender":"ชาย", "birthdate":"1/01/2007" } ]`
and so on

Comment: And what's your question about this?